# Column 'Value' does not belong to table

Tags: c#

I have stored some number data under column name Value in the `tblV` table of my database. I want to put the data from that column Value into `textbox1`.
But whenever I click the button it shows `Column 'Value' does not belong to table` error even though there is column `Value` in the table.  What is causing this problem?

The first one is class and second one is the code on button click event.

```
 public DataTable GetMaxno(decimal Licenseno)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=sudipDB;");
        string sql = "select Max(Value) from tblv where Licenseno=@licenseno";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Licenseno",Licenseno );
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(DT);
        return DT;
    }



 tryv tv = new tryv();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = tv.GetMaxno(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text));
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text= dt.Rows[0]["Value"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score 4):

Reason might be that your query does not return any aliases as `Value`. You can solve this with `select Max(Value) as Value` but instead of that, use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead which is exactly what you want. It returns first column of the first row.

A few things more;

- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command.
- Do not use `AddWithValue`. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising result sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.

```
public int GetMaxno(decimal Licenseno)
{
     using(var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=sudipDB;")
     using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
     {
        cmd.CommandText = "select Max(Value) from tblv where Licenseno = @licenseno";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@licenseno", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Licenseno;
        con.Open();
        return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     }
}
```

Then you can do;

```
textBox1.Text = tv.GetMaxno(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
string sql = "select Max(Value) as Value from tblv where Licenseno=@licenseno";
```